# Set Firefox window size on startup (or make it remember the last used size and not reset)

Tags: windows, firefox

Firefox 112 on Windows. I want the Firefox main window to have a certain size and position whenever I start it. When the Firefox window first opens it very briefly restores the last window size and position, but then the window moves and resizes every time. Well, almost... If I *only move* the window, without resizing it, then close it and restart Firefox it keeps its previous position, but if I resize it then both the size and position are changed.

I tried the trick of deleting xulstore.json, as well as editing it manually - that didn't help. The settings in xulstore.json seem to be respected when the window is first shown, but then something moves and resizes it - I don't know what. I tried disabling all extensions and it still happens. I'm using the default ("system") theme and have no other themes installed.

(Not a duplicate of [How do I make Firefox remember its window size?](https://superuser.com/questions/7744/how-do-i-make-firefox-remember-its-window-size) as I'm not maximizing the window. I tried the solutions there anyway, but none of them work now - the answer is 13 years old.)

Comment: Do you have any other app that might be resizing it, e.g., Windows built-in Snap (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) or a third-party tool such as WindowGrid (http://windowgrid.net/)?

Comment: No, nothing like that, and it only happens with Firefox.

Comment: Likely, storing your passwords and bookmarks, then completely removing the existing profile and reinstalling Firefox and importing data would fix it... but might not be worth the trouble.